# Javascript, on a map function I wrote, very short

Tags: javascript, arrays, callback

I am trying to get my function map to apply to each element of the array and then return the new array. Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

```
function addTwo(num)
{
 return num+2;
}

function map(array, callback)
{ 
  var new=[];
   for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
   {
     new.push(callback(array[i]));
   }  
}
var arr=[2,4,6,8];              
console.log(map(arr, addTwo));
```

Comment: do you see the error in the console? problem 1 - `new` is a reserved keyword - problem 2 - you're not using built in array methods to make your job simple, problem 3 - your map function creates an array, pushes stuff to it, then does nothing with it, you say you want to *return the new array*, yet your function doesn't return anything ... self evident problem right there

Comment: And next time, please describe the problem you're having instead of just saying that it doesn't work.

Comment: throw away the `function map`, and you'll see `console.log(arr.map(addTwo))` will do exactly what you want

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that new was reserved. How do I mark you as having answered the question @JaromandaX

Comment: no, there were **two** problems - your map function didn't return anything - added an answer -

Comment: Yeah, I knew that part, I was just going crazy trying to figure out what was wrong, so I hadn't included the return part here, because I was playing with the code on my screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to learn where you went wrong, so, here's your code rewritten with the two errors pointed out - `new` is reserved keyword, you can't have a var called `new` - you say you want your map function to return something, so, you should `return` something!

```
function addTwo(num) {
    return num+2;
}

function map(array, callback) { 
    var ret=[]; // use a non-reserved name for the array
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        ret.push(callback(array[i]));
    }
    return ret; // if you want to return it, then return it
}
var arr=[2,4,6,8];              
console.log(map(arr, addTwo));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in [**Array.prototype.map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this:

```js
function addTwo(num) {
    return num + 2;
}


var array = [1, 7, 5, 4];

console.log(array.map(addTwo));
```

**Note:** Your whole code code be done in one line (using [**arrow functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) like this:

```js
var array = [1, 7, 5, 4];

var newArray = array.map(n => n + 2);

console.log(newArray);
```